# matplotlib update plot in while-loop with dates as x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, while-loop

This might be obvious, so sorry in advance for this nooby question. I want to update a time series dynamically with matplotlib.pyplot. More precisely, I want to plot newly generated data in a while-loop.

This is my attempt so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import pandas as pd
import time

n = 100
x = np.NaN
y = np.NaN
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=x, value=y), index=np.arange(n)) # not neccessarily needed to have a pandas df here, but I like working with it.

# initialise plot and line
line, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
i=0

# simulate line drawing
while i <= len(df):

    #generate random data point
    newData = np.random.rand()

    # extend the data frame by this data point and attach the current time as index
    df.loc[i, "value"] = newData
    df.loc[i, "time"] = pd.datetime.now()

    # plot values against indices
    line.set_data(df['time'][:i], df['value'][:i])
    plt.draw()

    plt.pause(0.001)

    # add to iteration counter
    i += 1

    print(i)
```

This returns `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`. But as far as I can remeber, matplotlib doesn't have any problems with plotting dates on the x-axis (?).

Many thanks.

Comment: Isn't `pandas.plot` the one that plots dates seamlessly? Anyway, [there's a chapter in the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) for date-related plotting. [This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html) uses `ax.plot_date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andras Deak pointed out, you should tell pandas explicitly that your `time`  column is datetime. When you do `df.info()` at the end of your code, you will see that it takes `df['time']` as float64. You can achieve this with `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`.

I was able to make your code run, but I had to add a few lines of code. I was running it in a iPython (Jupyter) console and without the two lines `autoscale_view` and `relim`, it was not updating the plot correctly. What's left to do is a nice formatting of the x-axis labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import pandas as pd
import time

n = 100
x = np.NaN
y = np.NaN
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=x, value=y), index=np.arange(n)) # not neccessarily needed to have a pandas df here, but I like working with it.
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) #format 'time' as datetime object

# initialise plot and line
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'])

i=0

# simulate line drawing
while i <= len(df):    
    #generate random data point
    newData = np.random.rand()

    # extend the data frame by this data point and attach the current time as index
    df.loc[i, "value"] = newData
    df.loc[i, "time"] = pd.datetime.now()

    # plot values against indices, use autoscale_view and relim to readjust the axes
    line.set_data(df['time'][:i], df['value'][:i])
    axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    axes.relim()
    plt.draw()

    plt.pause(0.01)

    # add to iteration counter
    i += 1

    print(i)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you to edit your example such that the x axis correctly displays the datetime?

Comment: I tried but I was struggling. Somehow, the usual way with `set_major_formatter` using `matplotlib.dates` doesn't work with the time format of the pandas dataframe, and when I use a float-dataframe, it results in your float-error again. I can maybe try again tomorrow, but if you can not figure it out yourself, it would be probably best to create a new question since this one is already accepted (although people might just refer you to "matplotlib animation").